# modern react with redux

Tags: reactjs, npm

Unable to write file 'c:\Windows\System32\sony\src\asad.js' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\Windows\System32\sony\src\asad.js')

hi guys, I am new and beginner, I'm facing this error message when I create index.js file and I got this error message further more I deleted all folders from src directory so I need help how to resolve this problem how I able to create index.js file or should I reinstall and install it again?

C:\Windows\System32\sony>npm start

> sony@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
Name: index.js
Searched in: C:\Windows\System32\sony\src

C:\Windows\System32\sony>

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create your project in the windows System32 folder. This is usually reserved for operating system files, and as such has higher privileges (admin) to allow changes to files and folders. (It contains the kind of files that are often targeted by malicious code e.g. viruses, as Windows uses them to run)

Likely your IDE or development environment you are using has not been launched with administrator privileges so doesn't have permission to create or edit files in System32.

Try making your project in a new folder outside of "Windows\System32", say "C:\projects\myProject"

Comment: thanks for your kind response, can i use d drive and save files there to avoid this issue?

Comment: You should be able to yes, if it's just a normal hard drive or partition.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Windows user, but I believe that `C:\Windows\System32\` is an operational system folder. It's not a good practice to create your project within this folder.

Try creating your project inside with its files inside of `Documents` folder.

Comment: thanks for your kind response, can i use d drive and save files there to avoid this issue?